# nginx shows 404 on Auth0 Callback

Tags: nginx, auth0

I've setup Auth0 in my react application,
Everything works fine in my local environment
But when deployed on digital ocean using nginx,i get the 404 for Auth0 callback (The callback url also contains the token details in the url).

my nginx location config is as follows, do i need to add /callback ?

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/  =404;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx was not able to know what to do with the /callback,since i have used react router, and there's no file/folder corresponding to /callback it was showing 404
added /index.html, so react router will handle all the routing

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```